# How to compare hard-coded values with table data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to compare hard-coded values with table metadata (columns, data_types). How to realize in BigQuery the following usual SQL logic?

```
(select 'complaint_type' as column_name, 'STRING' as data_type
union all select 'complaint_description', 'STRING')s
except
select column_name, data_type 
from `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
```

Comment: not clear what the logic you have in mind - can you clarify. also what is expected result of above?

Comment: The query should return hard-coded columns which don't contain in a table or columns with different data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH hard_coded_values AS (
  SELECT 'complaint_type' AS column_name, 'STRING' AS data_type UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'complaint_description', 'STRING' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'complaint_test', 'STRING' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM hard_coded_values
WHERE NOT (column_name, data_type) IN (
  SELECT AS STRUCT column_name, data_type 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
)
```

with output

```
Row column_name     data_type    
1   complaint_test  STRING
```